# How can I set Anaconda3 python my default on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, anaconda, conda

I have anaconda 3 with python 3 that works perfectly in anaconda prompt but I want to make anaconda python my default python. file names 'python.exe' is located at 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' but when I go to PATH Variables there's no file named python in Anaconda3 folder. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;

These three settings should be set automatically in the path folder by Anaconda? If not done automatically, put them at the very beginning of the list.

Comment: God bless..I had done every other possible thing, except adding these 3